# Understanding Isomorphism on Binary Operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine whether the given map $\phi$ is an isomorphism of the following binary structures. Justify your answers.

$\langle\mathbb{R}, +\rangle$ with $\langle\mathbb{R}, +\rangle$, where $\phi(x) = x^5$, $\forall\: x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I don't understand what isomorphism means. Can anyone explain it? I tried reading the wiki but didn't understand it.

Comment: Do you understand what a homomorphism is? You will need to check that $\phi$ is a homomorphism and that it has an inverse which is also a homomorphism. (In this case checking that $\phi$ is bijective will be enough to give you the second part.)

Comment: @MattPressland is definition 3.4.1 what i'm looking for from http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/34.html ?

Comment: Yes, that's the right definition here. I'm being a bit careful because you've just said "binary structure" rather than group, and that definition is for isomorphism of groups. In your example, the binary structures *are* groups, but maybe you have other examples where they are not.

Answer (score 1):

A map is an *isomorphism* if it is a *homomorphism* (i.e. a map that preserves the operations given in the structure) and is *bijective* (i.e. has an *inverse*).

Now $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ has an inverse (namely $x\mapsto \sqrt[5]x$ which is well defined on whole $\Bbb R$ as $5$ is odd), *but*, it does not preserve $+$, meaning that in general
$$\phi(x+y) \ne\phi(x)+\phi(y)\,.$$

Comment: You need to be a bit careful about the "bijective iff inverse" part (I am not sure if it can fail when dealing purely with binary operations though).

Comment: Can you explain what you meant be "which is well defined on whole R as 5 is odd" ? What do you mean well defined on whole R?

Comment: oh nevermind. I've got it.

Comment: The map $x\mapsto x^n$ is a bijection on $\Bbb R$ if $n$ is odd, but negative numbers are not in its range if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the binary structures are isomorphic, Follow the following steps:

i.) define a function that gives the isomorphism of S with S'
ii.) show that the function is one to one
iii.) show that the function is onto
iv.) show homomorphism.

By this example it does not satisfy the last step which is the homomorphism. Because phi of m+n is not equal to phi of m plus phi of n.

Therefore not isomorphic.